# Expected value of a variable that depends on two other random variables, and one of these random variables depends on another random variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

I am trying to solve the problem using conditional expectations. The expected value H is depends on the waiting time T and a set threshold X (a real number that is a constant random variable during simulation runs).

But the waiting time T depends on the the number of new entrants Y in the system and these entrants arrive following a poisson process. T is however independent of X.

**Target:** Estimate unknown H given the distributions of T, Y and values for X

I am trying to represent this as follows but I somehow get lost along the way on evaluations of such nested expectations:

`E[H]= E[H|[E[T|Y]|X]]`

My questions is this even mathematically allowed because I cannot find a fitting property in the **laws of iterations of expectations** or the the **Tower Properties**.

How is this best represented from in statistics and calculus?

I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: I do not think that is how you iterate expectations.  Perhaps 
$E[H]= E\Big [E\big[E[E[H\mid X,Y,T]\mid X,Y]\mid X\big]\Big]$ or $E[H]= E\Big [E\big[E[E[H\mid X,T,Y]\mid T,Y]\mid Y\big]\Big]$

Comment: Thanks @Henry for this. It makes the integral even more complicated. The second option looks close to expressing the conditions but I am not sure of the ordering. Does it matter if I change `E[E[E[E[H|X,T,Y]|T,Y]|Y]]` to `E[E[E[E[H|X,T,Y]|T,Y]|X]]`?